# MongoDB - n-period average/min/max

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have time series data in a collection 'foo'. Each record has two fields - *foodate* and *foovalue*. What is the most efficient way to generate a n-period average, min and max of *foovalue* for every *foodate*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the aggregation framework:

```
> db.foo.insert([{ date: 0, value: 0 }, { date: 0, value: 1 }, { date: 1, value: 2 }])
> db.foo.count()
3
> db.foo.aggregate(
    { $group: {
        _id: '$date',
        avg: { $avg: '$value' } }
    },
    { $project: {
        // Rename '_id' to 'date', include 'avg'.
        date: '$_id',
        _id: false,
        avg: true
    } },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } })
```

Comment: @a-jesse-jiryu-davis Thanks.  Also, is is possible to do a rolling n-period calc within mongo?

Comment: No; for that you should just query the data and do the calculation in your programming language.